# Solving Maze Java Program

Tags: java, stack

I have a maze containing 3 letters `e` `g` `w`

- `e` for entrance
- `g` for goal
- and `w` represent the walls.

I found `e` but I have to move inside and print a dash where ever I move, when I find a wall I should go to previous dash(position added to a stack) and try all possible ways again.

```
for (int xy = p.row; xy < row; xy++) {
   for (int yz = p.col; yz < col; yz++) {

        if (s[xy][yz + 1] == ' ') {
            s[xy][yz + 1] = '.';
            p = new Pos(xy, yz + 1);
            st.push(p);
        }
        if (s[xy - 1][yz] == ' ') {
            s[xy - 1][yz] = '.';
            p = new Pos(xy - 1, yz);
            st.push(p);
        }
        if (s[xy + 1][yz] == ' ') {
            s[xy + 1][yz] = '.';
            p = new Pos(xy + 1, yz);
            st.push(p);
        }
        if ((yz >= 1) && (s[xy][yz - 1] == ' ')) {
            s[xy][yz - 1] = '.';
            p = new Pos(xy, yz - 1);
            st.push(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 0):

what it looks like is, when you get there you push the new position. Don't push it until you know its a wall.

before you move check all directions for valid moves.

```
if(ValidMove(array[x][y])){
    //if NOT WALL...Move
}else{
    //if IS WALL...check another
}
```

that way you have a stack full of valid moves. not walls you wont have to pop the invalid moves out to find the last one you were at.